# Error 403 with email checking program POST C#

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I have been trying to figure out why this post method isn't going through. I've been using Fiddler, and have been working on this for hours now. If someone could help that would be great.

```
private string getemail(string user, string pass)
{
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();

    var getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://account.mojang.com/migrate");
    cookies = (getRequest as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer;
    string[] tok = ReadResponse(getRequest).Split(new string[] { "name=\"authenticityToken\" value=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] toke = tok[1].Split('"');
    string token = toke[0];

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://account.mojang.com/migrate/check");
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31";
    request.ContentType = "text/plain";
    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            writer.Write("authenticityToken=" + token + "&mcusername=" + user + "&password=" + pass);
        }
    }
    using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) 
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Note: I know there is more I need to do after this, I just need to iron out this problem to get to that.

Answer (score 0):

Close your `StreamWriter` after writing content into request stream.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
{
  writer.Write("authenticityToken=" + token + "&mcusername=" + user + "&password=" + pass);
  writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Oh, forgot about that. Thank you, but the 403 error is still happening.

Comment: 403 is `forbidden` error. It seems related to authorization of your request.

Comment: This works when I use my browser. I've tried to mimic the request to the dot. I don't know what to do now, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you using `request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 ...` in your code. try to remove it and execute the code. and make sure you are passing valid authentication token to your service

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was the most recent UserAgent I tried. According to my readings a useragent is usually needed if there is a 403 error. I tried as you said anyway, but no luck.